# GUI logon into remote system

Tags: 11.10, ssh, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-x-session

I'm looking for something similar to RDP for linux.

I know VNC, but it doesnot work like RDP - it just sends images of screen, mouse position, keystrokes, etc. RDP just sends info that I've just clicked the button-widget.

I know I can forward Xs (I'm currently using this), but this way i can use only widnows I opened from console. Also, it works nice only with small gtk or qt based applications. Running eclipse is a nightmare.

What I'm looking for is to work remotely as if I was working on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) for this.

It has, in my opinion, the following advantages:

1. it is rather quick in the screen refresh and can be adapted to the type of network (56k modem, adsl, lan)
2. it can create a whole new session independent of what is shown on the server monitor